# Disable indexing fields for all fields in the document in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

- am using elasticsearch in my Java Spring application, for working with elasticsearch Spring JPA is used.
  I have a document and corresponding class in java with all fields that should not be indexed (I search through them for exact match using termFilter statement in java api)
  In my case I have to annotate each field

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)

and I get something like this

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(indexName = "message", type = "message")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("userName")
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String userName;


    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("topic")
    @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String topic;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("address")
    @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("recipient")
    @Field(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, type = FieldType.String)
    private String recipient;


}
```

Is there a possibility to put annotation on class in order not to duplicate it above all fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive your goal without `@Field` annotations using raw mappings + [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates)
Specify the path to your mappings in json file using `@Mapping` annotation

```
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings.json")
```

Then in `mappings.json` define your mapping like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "message": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "notanalyzed": {
                  "match":              "*", 
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":        "string",
                      "index":       "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

**Note:** I didn't test it, so please check for typos.